# Azure PS cmdlet for Disk Details in ARM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to list out details of Disks lying in one subscription. This is quite easy for all the disks in classic portal using - `Get-AzureDisk`

But, this doesn't list the disks which are lying in newer portal. I tried finding out equivalent command in ARM but I couldn't.

**NB**: I am using Azure PS Version 1.5.0. I don't want to list disk details of VM, rather I am interested in cleaning up orphaned disks in new portal.

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1312.

Comment: Not helpful @GauravMantri

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that ARM has no concept of a disk, it simply has a file that exists in storage. When you attach that file to a VM as a VHD it becomes a disk attached to a VM.

When you want to query the disk you need to query the VM, then you will get information about the disks that are attached to it.

As stated by [singhkays](https://github.com/singhkays) in the github issue in comments

> There's no direct API for getting the data disks. Get-AzureRmVM returns data disks as part of the VM return

```
StorageProfile : {
"DataDisks": [
 {
  "Lun": 0,
  "Caching": "ReadWrite",
  "CreateOption": "Empty",
  "DiskSizeGB": 1,
  "Name": "data-disk-1",
  "SourceImage": null,
  "VirtualHardDisk": {
  "Uri": "http://jenkinswinstore.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/data-disk-1.vhd"
   }
  }
],
```

Comment: What if I have deleted a VM keeping it's vhd. How will I get detail of that vhd in ARM?

Comment: You would need to look through your storage accounts and manually locate it

Answer (score 1):

> rather I am interested in cleaning up orphaned disks in new portal.

If you just want to find the orphaned disks in new portal, actually, you are trying to find the unleased vhd.

Then, all you need is querying the "ICloudBlob.Properties.LeaseStatus" property of vhd files.

I write a sample script for you, it works for me.

```
$RGName = "stlvm"
$SAName = "stlvmstorage"
$ConName = "vhds"
$TempObj = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject
$TempObj |Add-Member -Name BlobName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $null
$TempObj |Add-Member -Name LeaseState -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $null
$Keylist = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $RGName -StorageAccountName $SAName
$Key = $Keylist[0].Value
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SAName -StorageAccountKey $Key
$List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob *.vhd -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx
$List | ForEach-Object { $TempObj.BlobName = $_.Name; $TempObj.LeaseState = $_.ICloudBlob.Properties.LeaseState; $TempObj }
```

Here is the screenshot of my lab:

[image: Sample]

Comment: I am going to test your script. Will upvote and tick accordingly. Cheers !